# "save the date" vs "safe the date"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I sometimes see "safe the date" on webpages. I always thought it was "save the date" as in "saving the date to a calendar". Also, there is no verb [safe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/safe).

Using "safe the date" feels wrong to me.

And, is "save the date" a phrase that is commonly used or is there a better phrase?

AFAIK it means something like "please save the date to your calendar (or remember the date and block it)".

Comment: 'Safe' is not a verb. 'Safe the date' is an error. You could say 'reserve the date' if you wanted.

Comment: I have heard phrases like *"safe the gun"* meaning to make the weapon safe (I imagine it means to remove all the bullets and check that there is no possibility of it firing). I think "*safe the date"* derives from mishearing the word *"save"*, they can sound quite similar and thus be confused.

Comment: Save the date is the standard thing to write when you are advising people of a forthcoming event but are not yet ready to issue a formal invitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "save the date". "Safe the date" is a malapropism, like "for all-intensive purposes" (for all *intents and* purposes), "make my words" (*mark* my words), etc.

Comment: Like "Why don't you make like a tree, and get out of here"